# d3js draw svg rectangle and line issue

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying to draw a rectangle and horizontal line below it. As it is nothing is being drawn and I can't work out why. I'd like to keep the basic structure (separate functions for rectangle and line drawing) if possible as I am drawing multiple rectangles and lines of different sizes/lengths. I'm new to d3.js (and js in general) so any improvements are welcome.

file so_rect.js:

```
function Rectangle(x, y, height, width) {
    this.x_axis = x;
    this.y_axis = y;
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
}

function Line(x, y, width) {
    this.x_axis = x;
    this.y_axis = y;
    this.width = width;
}

function renderLine(){
    console.log('>>renderLine');
    var line = new Line ('10', '55', '200');
    var stringifiedLine = JSON.stringify(line);
    var jsonLine = JSON.parse(stringifiedLine);
    var g = d3.select("#svgContainer");
    var lines = g.selectAll("line")
        .data(jsonLine)
        .enter()
        .append("line");
    var lengthLines = lines
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.x_axis; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.x_axis+ d.width; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.y_axis; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.y_axis+ 20; })
        .style("stroke", "black")
        .style("stroke_width", 2);
}

function renderBox(){
    console.log('>>renderBox');
    var localRectangle = new Rectangle (10,10,200,50);
    var stringifiedRectangle = JSON.stringify(localRectangle);
    var jsonRectangle = JSON.parse(stringifiedRectangle);
    var svgContainer = d3.select ('#svgPlaceholder').append ("svg")
        .attr ("width", '250')
        .attr ("height", '100')
        .attr ("id", "svgContainer");
    var g = svgContainer.append("g")
        .attr("id","svgBox");
    var rectangles = g.selectAll ("rect")
        .data (jsonRectangle)
        .enter ()
        .append ("rect");

    var rectangleAttributes = rectangles
        .attr ("x", function (d) {
            return d.x_axis;
        })
        .attr ("y", function (d) {
            return d.y_axis;
        })
        .attr ("height", function (d) {
            return d.height;
        })
        .attr ("width", function (d) {
            return d.width;
        })
        .style("stroke", "black");

}

renderBox();
renderLine();
```

file so_rect.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

</head>
<body>

<div class="content" id="svgPlaceholder">Put box here</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="d3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="so_rect.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: maybee this one helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39927308/how-to-draw-a-rectangle-with-d3-js-based-on-2-diametrical-points-and-no-length-o/39927309#39927309

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
   var lines = g.selectAll("line")
        .data(jsonLine)
```

Data expects a json array.

```
var lines = g.selectAll("line")
    .data([jsonLine]) //array of line objects
    .enter()
```

Same for rectangles

Instead of

```
var rectangles = g.selectAll ("rect")
    .data (jsonRectangle)
```

pass an array of json data like this:

```
var rectangles = g.selectAll ("rect")
    .data ([jsonRectangle]) //array of json array rectangle.
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/uNuuSwZl8sEOOy7tpQaj?p=preview)

Hope this helps!